# MongoDB performance for queries

Tags: mongodb

I'm having issues with my database right now with hundreds of people on our site. Looking at my current operations in my Compose.io dashboard I see that this is one query that has been running for a very long time.

I have an index on _id: 1, owner: 1 and date: -1. Any idea why this query could be taking so long and is locking my entire database? I can also see the number of yields is 268 which is very high which seems problematic.

[image: Slow Query]

This is another query that has been running for half a second. It seems to be locking the entire database. Why is this?
[image: Slow query 2]